# How to ssh with onion address on window 10?

Tags: onion-services, ssh

I made a secure drop server.

For better security, I've set up onion service for ssh.

How to ssh with onion address in Windows 10?

`torify ssh root@myserver.onion`

doesn't exist in window 10.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to torify - there is a better tool called [Bitvise SSH client](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download) that just needs a SOCKS proxy to be specified for a connection, that's it! Don't forget to set the proxy to resolve host names for dot-onions to work properly! I'm using for years and there were not a single problem with it. Also it features a good pack of SSH-based tools in one toolkit - just check it out ;)